# Different header in primefaces datatable and xls export

Tags: jsf, primefaces, apache-poi

I need to have different text headers in datatable and in exported excel file.
I can do this by customize `postProcessor` method for `p:dataexporter`.
Are they another posibilities to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'different text headers'? Do you have an example / working code?

Comment: @siebz0r it means that Column1 has a text header like "Column 1 DT" in datatable and "Column 1 Excel" in the exported excel file.